# Can I transfer database from public to development site using ftp?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, ftp

Can I transfer database (products & phots, clients, sales history) from public to development site using ftp?

Comment: why not? dump your database and copy it over

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about databases and file transfer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have SSH access to the site, you can create a database dump from the admin panel.

1. Navigate to System > Tools > Backups

   [image: screenshot]
2. Click "Database Backup" for database dump or "Database and Media Backup" for a database dump plus archive of catalog images. Confirm the dialog.

   [image: screenshot]
3. Choose a file name, wait until backup is finished.
4. In your FTP client, navigate to `var/backups` and download the created backup archive. You can also try to download the file directly from the admin grid instead of using FTP. To do so, click on the "gz" link:

   [image: screenshot]